# Haskell datatype to Java(OO)

Tags: java, haskell

I'm trying to convert a simple Haskell datatype and a function to OO. 
But I'm confused..

Have the following Haskell type for arithmetic calculation:

```
data Expr = Lit Int | 
      Add Expr Expr |
   deriving Show

--Turn the expr to a nice string
showExpr :: Expr -> String 
showExpr (Lit n) = show n
showExpr (Add e1 e2) = "(" ++ showExpr e1 ++ "+" ++ showExpr e2 ++ ")"
```

Now I'm trying to convert..

```
public interface Expr {
  String showExpr(String n);
} 

// Base case
public class Lit implements Expr {
  String n;

  public Lit(String n) {
    this.n = n;
  }

  @Override
  public String ShowExpr() {
    return n;
  }
}

public class Add implements Expr {
  Expr a;
  Expr b;

  public Add(Expr aExpr, Expr bExpr) {
    this.a = aExpr;
    this.b = bExpr;
  }

  public String ShowExpr() {
    return "(" + a.ShowExpr() + "+" + b.ShowExpr() + ")";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lit firstLit  = new Lit("2");
    Lit secLit = new Lit("3");
    Add add = new Add(firstLit,secLit);
    System.out.println(add.ShowExpr());
  }
}
```

This will result in "(2+3)", it's correct answer.

But.. I'm not sure.. is this the right way to think about it and model it in OO ?

Is't a good representation of the Haskell datatype ?

Comment: I think your convertion is real good. The only thing I can comment it that Expr should be an abstract Class instead of a interface. And don't use java for this kind of problems becouse haskell are much better at this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's copy the code as closely as we can.

Here are some properties that the Haskell data structure has:

1. It has the type `Expr` and two constructors `Lit` and `Add`
2. You cannot add or remove constructors from the "outside"

So, if we want these properties to stay true in the Java version, you should do it like this:

```java
public abstract class Expr {
    // So that you can't add more subclasses outside this block
    private Expr() {}

    // Simulate pattern matching:
    // (This CAN be done with instanceof, but that's ugly and not OO)
    public boolean isLit() {
        return false;
    }
    public boolean isAdd() {
        return false;
    }
    public Lit asLit() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This is not a Lit");
    }
    public Add asAdd() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This is not an Add");
    }

    public static class Lit extends Expr {
        public final int n;
        public Lit(int n) {
            this.n = n;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isLit() {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public Lit asLit() {
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static class Add extends Expr {
        public final Expr a, b;
        public Lit(Expr a, Expr b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isAdd() {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public Add asAdd() {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, to convert `showExpr`:

```java
public static String showExpr(final Expr expr) {
    if(expr.isLit()) {
        return Integer.toString(expr.asLit().n);
    } else if(expr.isAdd()) {
        return "(" + expr.asAdd().a + "+" + expr.asAdd().b + ")";
    }
}
```

You can put `showExpr` as a static method in the `Expr` class. I would *not* make it an instance method, because that strays further from the Haskell version.

Comment: I see no real difference between `if(e.isLit()) { Lit l = e.asLit(); }` and `if(e instanceof Lit) { Lit l = (Lit)e; }`. Haskell-style pattern matching is inherently not OO, so trying to hide that fact with methods that simulate `instanceof` and casts brings nothing to the code.

Comment: @yshavit, you are right, of course, but I think that the style I present leads to easier-to-read code, and less bugs like `if(foo instanceof Foo) { ((Bar)foo).bla(); }` due to refactoring (`Foo != Bar`). I might also for example want to make `Add` and `Lit` into private classes and use factory methods for them, and in that case, `instanceof` won't work.

Comment: Whether `e instanceof Lit` is more or less readable than `e.isLit()` I'll leave as a matter of opinion. :)  But note that if they're private classes, `e.asLit().n` won't work, either.

Answer (score 2):

I would slightly turn this on its head: each Haskell class becomes a Java interface, and `instance ...where` (or `derives`) becomes `implements`.

So, `class Show a` becomes

```
interface Showable {
    String show();
}
```

Now then, what does the `Expr` data type do? It combines various Haskell constructors -- aka Java classes -- into a single type, and also says they all are covered by Haskell classes (ie implement Java interfaces). So, I would then say that the data type `Expr` becomes

```
interface Expr extends Showable {}
```

and the `Lit` constructor, for instance, becomes:

```
class Lit implements Expr {
    @Override
    String show() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now you can have Java collections that include both `Lit` and `Add` instances (e.g. `List<Expr>`), and for any `Expr`, you know it `implements Showable`.

Note that by pulling `Showable` as its own interface (rather than putting its method directly on `Expr` as you did), I allow other, completely unrelated Java classes to also implement it. This is akin to how anybody can define an `instance ... where` of any Haskell class you define.

Finally, there's a couple mismatches between open-world and closed-world policies here. Haskell's `instance ... where` is open-world, whereas Java's `implements` is closed. But Haskell's constructors-per-type is closed, whereas Java's `extends` is *mostly* open.

There's not much you can do about `implements` being closed, but you can close the `extends` with an abstract class and a private constructor, so that's what I would do (if you want that behavior). Tweaking the above a bit, we get:

```
public abstract class Expr implements Showable {
    private Expr() {
        // hide the ctor from the outside world, so nobody else
        // can extend this class
    }

    public static class Lit extends Expr {
        ...
    }

    public static class Add extends Expr {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be okay if the original code would use a type class, but I think this is overkill for modelling a simple ADT.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate it that way:

```
public abstract class Expr {

    public static Expr Lit(final int n) {
        return new Expr() {
            public String showExpr() {
                return "" + n;
            }
        };
    }

    public static Expr Add(final Expr e1, final Expr e2) {
        return new Expr() {
            public String showExpr() {
                return String.format("(%s+%s)", e1.showExpr(), e2.showExpr());
            }
        };
    }

    public abstract String showExpr();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Expr firstLit = Lit(2);
        Expr secLit = Lit(3);
        Expr add = Add(firstLit, secLit);
        System.out.println(add.showExpr());
    }
}
```

In Haskell `Lit` and `Add` are no subtypes (there is no such thing in Haskell) but just `Expr`essions. There is no need to expose the subclasses in Java, which I why I could use anonymous classes hidden in some methods. This works perfect, as long as you don't need pattern matching (which is hard to model in Java anyway, as the simple `instanceof` test gets soon messy with more complicated examples).

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, but could be a little more idiomatic. You can use `final` to make fields immutable, for example. You might as well replace `showExp` with `toString` (which is declared in `Object`), unless you want `toString` to do something different. Using [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is a little cleaner than concatenating several strings, in my opinion. Finally, I would have `Lit` store an `int`, since it's more compact and type safe.

Here's how I would translate it:

```
abstract class Exp {
  // Force subclasses to override Object.toString.
  public abstract String toString();
}

class Lit extends Exp {
  final int value;

  Lit(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return Integer.toString(value);
  }
}

class Add extends Exp {
  final Exp a, b;

  Add(Exp a, Exp b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return String.format("(%s + %s)", a, b);
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lit firstLit = new Lit(2);
    Lit secLit = new Lit(3);
    Add add = new Add(firstLit, secLit);
    System.out.println(add);
  }
}
```